# Unquoting doesn't always work in the new Stacks Editor

Tags: bug, blockquote, stacks-editor

Unquoting doesn't always work in the new Stacks Editor. Example:

[image]

Markdown:

```
> I have been detained when trying to walk out of tuas and was given a warning. DO NOT walk on Tuas. [Anish Sheela](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67804/anish-sheela "13,800 reputation") [4 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/can-one-walk-across-the-border-between-singapore-and-malaysia-via-the-johor-sing#comment471777_184549)
>
> Pedestrians are definitely not permitted on the Second Link, which is also *much* longer (10+ km) and impractical even if it was allowed. [lambshaanxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/lambshaanxy "99,234 reputation") [1 hour ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/can-one-walk-across-the-border-between-singapore-and-malaysia-via-the-johor-sing#comment471783_184549)
```

Comment: Does it ever work outside of markdown mode? I just tried to unquote a single word and it doesn't work. It only works in markdown mode for me.